# Developing Linux software on Windows

Tags: windows, linux

I want to write software for the Linux platform, but I would like to do this on a Windows OS. I'm only developing Linux software for a remote server of mine, so it wouldn't be worth it to switch to Linux just for that. I don't think it's as simple as using a cross-compiler, because I will be writing code that uses headers specifically for Linux, and I would like to test the programs on Windows. I don't want to use VirtalBox etc.

Comment: So you want to test, in Windows, a program that is compiled for Linux, but without using an emulator? That might be tough..

Comment: if you want to use linux-specific APIs and be able to test them on your windows machine, you will need an emulated/virtualizated environment at some point.

Comment: @GolezTrol I know I'd have to use some sort of emulator, but not VirtualBox or the likes, which would require me to have a separate development environment.

Comment: depending on what you are actually doing, you might even be able to use java...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If possible, install the entire development environment on the linux server. Then install an Xserver (e.g XMing) and an ssh client (e.g putty) on your Windows box. Then run the dev. environment remotely.

The big pro of doing this is that the linux windows integrate seamlessly in the Windows enviornment. I used to work with dual platform development and had a virtual linux box on my PC. Still, I used ssh+X-forwarding to access it. This way I got full copy-paste support etc. between the environments.

Comment: I love VSCode + Remote Extension.  It allows you to develop as if you are in Windows, but you all the commands such as editing files are actually being forwarded to a remote Linux machine via SSH.  It's all seamless, it just feels like you are developing locally.

Comment: @pilkch Wow, I've been around on Stack Overflow for too long - a comment to a answer that's nearly 10 years old. With risk of sounding like a grumpy old dev: VS Code was unheard of when I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Now [WSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/commandline/wsl/about) (also known as "Bash on Windows") exists, you can run native Linux binaries directly on Windows. With [snapcraft](https://snapcraft.io/) you can package Linux applications entirely under Windows, without using a VM. Might be a better option. I made a super quick [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JKavx9Vpzk) to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

[CoLinux](http://www.colinux.org/) allows you to run linux side-by-side with Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and virtualize a Linux environment from within Windows. I do the reverse of what you are trying to do and run Windows from Linux, and it works quite well.

Comment: I said I would like to avoid that :/. I want a more "native" feel.

Comment: You *can* get a native feel. With seamless mode, the VM disappears and you are left with only floating windows from the Linux environment.

Comment: Native feel in terms of having Linux side-by-side with Windows. Using VirtualBox, I believe I would have to set up a separate development environment.

Comment: Ahh, that makes a bit more sense. The twice-upvoted answer would be the best then. I've done that before, and it does work somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with .NET and C# you can use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) for your client.

You can use Visual Studio to develop and the Mono runtime one Linux to run the application.

You do need to keep away from windows specific code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) could help. You don't need an entire virtual machine and only the api is emulated.

Comment: But could I test the programs I compile?

Comment: I believe so, if what you use is supported in cygwin.

Comment: No. You cannot run a linux binary on cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

You could use g++ in cygwin to target a linux binary.  It's a pain to setup as you noted you'll need the entire toolchain (not just the compiler).  I've used [crosstool](http://kegel.com/crosstool/) (domain name makes me giggle every time) in the past with success. It looks like someone did the work already http://metamod-p.sourceforge.net/cross-compiling.on.windows.for.linux.html

However I've never targeted linux from windows.  I'd install a virtual linux box, way easier and you're likely going to want to do your testing on a real linux box before going live.

Cygwin isn't linux so you can't test your linux binaries there.

Out of curiosity what's keeping you from doing the development on linux?  If the server the app runs on isn't mission critical you could even develop there.

Comment: Having a separate development environment for Linux is more work than simply being able to right-click a Linux binary and choose "Run with Linux compatibility", which would be ideal.